# Sinatra 'post' route not calling template.

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, sinatra

I have a simple app written in Ruby using Sinatra. I am trying to make a form that live updates the page based on what info is written in the form. For example, a form has a "name" field. A user fills in their name, presses "go" and the page (without refreshing) displays "Welcome {name}".

This is what I have working:

my app.rb

```
get '/examples' do
    erb :example
end

post '/examples' do
    post = params[:post]
    @name = post['name']

    puts "HERE"
    erb :example
end
```

My example.erb file (not the entire file, only the form)

```
<% if @name then %>
    <%= @name %>
<% end %>


<form id="myForm" action="/examples" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="post[name]" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Name" />
</form>
```

And my JS file:

```
// bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
    alert("Thank you for your comment!");
});
```

it works up the bottom of the post route in my app.rb file. "HERE" is printed to the terminal and then alert is displayed but the page just sits there and isn't updated. 
I have even tried a redirect call in the post route but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a problem coming from the javascript, if I do a standard post with refresh, the code works fine.

Comment: prevent you form submit to make a "submit". send a ajax request instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)? If so -- I think what's happening is that jQuery is intercepting and performing the post, meaning that the page (and view) won't get reloaded; therefore <%= @name %> will never be evaluated (because @name wasn't available when the view was initially loaded).

You might want to use jQuery Form's options, which allow you to set a target HTML element that will be updated with the response of your post (see an example [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm)).

I'd also recommend giving the response its own view, otherwise you'll end up returning everything else in your example.erb view as part of the response.

Updated example.erb:

```
<div id="output1">
</div>

<form id="myForm" action="/examples" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="post[name]" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Name" />
</form>

<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() { 

    var options = { 
      target: '#output1',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    }; 

    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options, function() { 
      alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
    }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

Updated web.rb

```
get '/examples' do
    erb :example
end

post '/examples' do    
  post = params[:post]
  @name = post['name']

  puts "HERE "

  erb :response
end
```

New view -- response.erb:

```
<% if @name then %>
  <%= @name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying to stay on the same page though so the user has a seamless experience. With this method, the user enters data on ':examples' template and then is redirected to :response template.

Comment: Sure thing. The above should keep the user on the same page as-is (I believe)... the jQuery Form posts an AJAX call to /examples and shouldn't redirect the user away from the current page. Using erb :example for the post response will work, but it also returns a bunch of duplicate stuff back to the view, essentially doubling the page, if that makes sense (the above code should be workable if you want to give it a shot).

Comment: Got it. That makes sense, sorry I was confusing views and templates. Thanks!